# How to present external data in Sonarqube?

Tags: sonarqube, getgauge

I like to include Gauge (http://gauge.org) results in SonarQube (LTS 6.7.1), basically by simply include execution information for a project (which is stored locally in a junit xml file).

What spec and scenarios have been run etc.

But I completely fail on how to integrate this in sonarqube. I managed to add a new page to sonarqube, but how can I retrieve the values to display ?

So my thought was to have a `Sensor` reading the Gauge report file and publishing the information. But all the `sensorContext.newXXX` methods seem wrong to use for this.

Any advise on how to extract and present external information in SonarQube ? Any best practices available ?

Thanks